# Was my prayer valid given that it was performed after masturbating and performing ghusl without rinsing my mouth and nose?

Tags: salat, ghusl, masturbation

From 12-16 I was masturbating. I have stopped now. But before, when I was performing ghusl, I never rinsed my mouth or nose because I didn't know it was farz. I thought only pouring water was farz. Was my prayer and quran recitation and fasts valid?

Comment: Who made that fard?

Comment: I am Sunni Hanafi btw and visit college so weekends are the only time where I can read Sunna and nawafi for every namaz. I heard that they can make up farz that was missed http://www.sistani.org/english/qa/01198/#15302

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam we are not like a typical internet forum. To learn more about this site and the SE model i strongly recommend you to take the [tour] and visit our [help].

Comment: You say you are sunni Hanafi and then give a link of a shi'a marji'?